# Asp.net c# reverse dns lookup to get computer name fail for some client

Tags: c#, asp.net, reverse-dns

In order to get the computer name, I used the reverse dns lookup method to get computer name from ip address. However, it works for some client and some client facing error on that when they browse the website publish under iis which run on anonymous authentication. I try to figure out the error exception which mean if the host was not readable it will return ip address instead of computer name which will be causing error for client side. I have stuck on this few weeks, anyone can help me regarding how to write the exception code?

Comment: So you have a local network where you don't have a proper local DNS server?

Comment: Do you mind sharing a code sample to illustrate your points?

Comment: Please share what have you done so far and also more details about exception will help..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622246/c-sharp-fail-to-get-some-client-computer-name/59622760#59622760

Comment: Here was i doing but until now cannot get solution, so i think better put exception code but I cannot get any reference online, guys please help

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339624/how-to-ask-same-question-again-on-stack-overflow

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128226/can-i-ask-same-question-again-if-nobody-has-answered